# Chi-squared goodness-of-fit test whether the data follows binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

The number of boys in 500 families with 5 children is investigated. There were 20 families with no boy, 75 with 1, 145 with 2, 140 with 3, 85 with 4, and 35 with 5 boys. Decide (with level of significance α = 0.05) whether the number of boys in a 5-children family follows binomial distribution.

For testing that the data has a binomial distribution using Pearson's chi-squared test: Let X be the number of boys with probability of getting boy $p$ . I want to test $B(5,p)$ is a reasonable model for the distribution of X. The sample mean is 2.6. After this I get stuck.

I was wondering if someone can help me?  Thanks!

Comment: I can help you, but I want to see some things you've tried. You mention the sample mean is 2.6? Where did you get that value from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it is time for a more complete answer.

You have values $x = (0,1,2,3,4,5)$ with corresponding
observed frequencies $f = (20,75,145,140,85,35),$
totaling $m = \sum_x f_x = 500.$ Relative frequencies are $r_x = f_x/m.$

Thus the sample mean is $\bar X = \sum_x xr_x = 2.6,$ which is
the estimate of the binomial mean $\mu = n\theta,$ where $n = 5$ is
the number of independent trials and $\theta$ is the success probability.
Because the estimated mean is $\bar X = \hat \mu = n\hat \theta = 2.6,$
we have $\hat \theta = 2.6/5 = 0.52.$

```
x = 0:5; f = c(20,75,145,140,85,35) 
sum(f) 
## 500 
r = f/sum(f);  sum(x*f)/500 
## 2.6 
p = 2.6/5;  p 
## 0.52
```

Our null hypothesis is that the distribution $Binom(5, 0.52)$ is an
appropriate model for the number of successes. Under this distribution
the probabilities $p_x$ of the values $x$ are given as `pdf` in the R output below.
Under this binomial model, the expected frequencies $E_x = 500p_x,$ also
shown below.

```
pdf = dbinom(x, 5, .52);  E = 500*pdf
cbind(x, f, r, pdf, E)
##     x   f    r       pdf         E
##     0  20 0.04 0.0254804  12.74020
##     1  75 0.15 0.1380188  69.00941
##     2 145 0.29 0.2990408 149.52038
##     3 140 0.28 0.3239608 161.98042
##     4  85 0.17 0.1754788  87.73939
##     5  35 0.07 0.0380204  19.01020
```

The chi-squared goodness-of-fit (GOF) statistic is
$$Q = \sum_x \frac{(f_x - E_x)^2}{E_x},$$
which is approximately distributed as $Chisq(df  = 6-2).$
The approximation is valid because all of the $E_x > 5.$
If we had been given the specific binomial parameters $n$ and $\theta,$
the degrees of freedom would have been $6 - 1,$ but we have
estimated one parameter $\theta$ so $df = 6-2 = 4.$

Good agreement ('fit') between the observed frequencies
$f_x$ and the expected frequencies $E_x$ gives small values of $Q.$
(Very unlikely perfect agreement would give $Q = 0.$) We reject
the model $Binom(5, 0.52)$ for large values of $Q$.

The 95th percentile
of $Chisq(df = 4)$ is 9.49, so we reject at the 5% level of significance
if $Q > 9.49.$ For our data, the value of the test statistic
is $Q = 21.31$, so we reject the model as unreasonable at the 5% level.
The P-value 0.0003 is the probability $P(Q > 21.31),$ if the true distribution
were $Q \sim Chisq(df = 4).$ The chances of seeing the observed frequencies
$f_x$ if the true model where $Binom(5, 0.52)$ are very small. 
[Looking at the earlier table, we see one major discrepancy
is that we have many fewer (140) than the expected number (161.98) of families with three boys.]

```
Q = sum((f-E)^2/E); Q 
## 21.31109 
qchisq(.95, 6-2) 
## 9.487729
1 - pchisq(21.3, 4)
## 0.0002761148
```

One way to visualize the poor fit is to compare the probabilities $p_x$ (bars) from the
hypothetical model with the relative frequencies ($\times$'s) $r_x$ actually
observed. But such graphical comparisons do not reveal the total number
of cases observed, and so they should only be viewed along with results
from formal GOF tests.

[image]

Comment: @Brandon: Here is the test we discussed in chat.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to calculate the expected number in each category assuming that the distribution is binomial. Then the test statistic $\chi^2$ is based on the sum of square differences between the expected numbers ($E_i$) and the actual ones ($O_i$). See [this description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).